# Why won't date equality work in R when doing subset on a data frame

Tags: r

Here is a simple data

```
Date;Time;Global_active_power;Global_reactive_power;Voltage;Global_intensity;Sub_metering_1;Sub_metering_2;Sub_metering_3
16/12/2006;17:24:00;4.216;0.418;234.840;18.400;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2007;17:25:00;5.360;0.436;233.630;23.000;0.000;1.000;16.000
16/12/2008;17:26:00;5.374;0.498;233.290;23.000;0.000;2.000;17.000
```

I wrote the following code

```
data <- read.table("foo.txt", sep=";", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
subset(data, Date=as.Date("2006-12-16"))
```

but the output is all 3 rows instead of 1

curiously. Greater than sign works but not `=`

```
subset(data, Date>as.Date("2006-12-16"))
```

returns 2 rows as expected.

Some googling reveals that this works

```
subset(data, Date %in% as.Date("2006-02-01"))
```

but why not `=`?

Comment: Try `==` instead of `=` or use `%in%` if there are multiple dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the `?subset`

```
 ## S3 method for class 'data.frame'
 subset(x, subset, select, drop = FALSE, ...)
```

> subset: logical expression indicating elements or rows to keep:
>             missing values are taken as false.

`=` is `assigning` value to a name, whereas `==` operator allows comparison of values and returns a logical expression

So,

```
subset(data, Date == as.Date("2006-02-01"))
```

works as well as `%in%`.  I would use `%in%` if there are multiple dates values as `==` would be faster.